# Play mp3 file continuously in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play mp3 file continuously in background. I mean if i an on first activity mp3 file should start in background. Now, If I navigate to second activity then also i want to play file continuously. File should not be played from start in second activity.

Comment: Use a Service to play it in the background - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mediaPlayer.start();
            }

            });

    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Just start it in service

```
   private boolean isAppShown() {

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    boolean locked = km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = i.next();

        if (info.uid == getApplicationInfo().uid && info.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && !locked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

This is how you can check the state, but now you should decide where to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I used service and your code to start player. But the problem is when i kill the application the sound is still playing in background even my app is not running.

Comment: You are welcome! So for your question, the problem is that the application is actually there (still running), to stop the sound you should determine if at least on of your activities is active and then stop the sound inside the server. But this is another question i guess ;)

Comment: Or, you can send the message to the service to stop the sound, when your last (or first) activity calls onStop()

Answer (score 3):

```
 MediaPlayer ring= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.alertsound);
 ring.setLooping(true);
 ring.start();
```

Comment: if you play sound on click continuously then this code working

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This is a working music play example. 
You've to write a background service in order to play music.
    [Music Player](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer)